# find element with xpath in treeview

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, treeview

I have this html and i need to click on {**Syców**}{**3002**} using by Selenium WebDriver in Visual Studio. Please help. I have that xpath but this dont work.

My xpath:

```
ClickElementByXPath("//div[@id='ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_UpdatePanel1']/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/a/font/b");
```

HTML

```
<?IMPORT NAMESPACE = TVNS IMPLEMENTATION = "http://192.168.3.11/webctrl_client/1_0/treeview.htc" DECLARENAMESPACE />
<tvns:treeview tabIndex=0 id=ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14 hideFocus style="OVERFLOW-X: auto" onfirequeuedevents="javascript: window.setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderCenter$ContentPlaceHolderBody$nitNetworkItem$ctl14\',\'\')', 0, 'JavaScript')" onselectedindexchange="javascript: if (event.oldTreeNodeIndex != event.newTreeNodeIndex) this.queueEvent('onselectedindexchange', event.oldTreeNodeIndex + ',' + event.newTreeNodeIndex)" oncheck="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent('oncheck', this.clickedNodeIndex)" oncollapse="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent('oncollapse', this.clickedNodeIndex)" onexpand="javascript: if (this.clickedNodeIndex != null) this.queueEvent('onexpand', this.clickedNodeIndex)" systemImagesPath="/webctrl_client/1_0/treeimages/" HelperID="__ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14_State__" selectedNodeIndex="0" HoverNodeIndex __scrollLeft="0" __scrollTop="0">
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="folder" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/folder.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="folderGPZ" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/folder.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="137" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz - set.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="137a" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz A.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz - set A.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="137w" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz W.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/gpz - set W.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="2" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja - set.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="2a" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja A.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja - set A.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="2w" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja W.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/stacja - set W.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="23" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="23a" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag A.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set A.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="23w" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag W.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set W.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="245" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="245a" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag A.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set A.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="245w" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag W.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Ciag - set W.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="D" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default - set.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="Da" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default A.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default - set A.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenodetype Type="Dw" ImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default W.gif" ExpandedImageUrl="/webctrl_client/1_0/Images/energetics/Default - set W.gif">
   </tvns:treenodetype>
   <tvns:treenode Type="folder" Expanded="True" NodeData="0$0$0$False$False$False" ID="#0$0$0$False$False$False#">
      GPZ
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300434171$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300434171$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>PZ/RS Wojciechowo</b>}{<b>0700</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300432739$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300432739$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>Kępno</b>}{<b>3001</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300432740$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>Syców</b>}{<b>3002</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300432741$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300432741$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>Wieruszów</b>}{<b>3003</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300501049$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300501049$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>Kępno Wsch.</b>}{<b>3004</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
      <tvns:treenode Type="137" NodeData="137$4300499223$43$False$False$False" CheckBox="False" ID="#137$4300499223$43$False$False$False#">
         {<b>Obcy</b>}{<b>9999</b>}
      </tvns:treenode>
   </tvns:treenode>
</tvns:treeview>
```

Comment: try this `ClickElementByXPath("(//*[contains(., '{Syców}{3002}')])[last()]");`

Comment: Can you please post the HTML code that is rendered in browser.

Comment: Please for help. That can by any xpath, id, tagname, linktext, name, cssSelector. I have no idea what do. Nothing work.

Comment: try with id=#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False# it works fine. May be is due to some loading time. Try Thread.sleep and then go for id=#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False# click.

Comment: So this should look like this? ClickElementByXPath("//*[@id='#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False#']");

Comment: you no need to go for xpath if the id is unique you can directly go for driver.findElement(By.id("#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False#")).click(); - the code is in Java

Comment: In C# look like this driver.FindElement(By.Id("#137$4300432741$43$False$False$False#")).Click(); - but this dont work :( I am frustrated

Comment: Is there any error log is being shown. Can you past that ?

Comment: Ok that help me, but i have new problem. I cant click confirm button because is not visible from TreeView. First i go to treeview id and click then i click "Syców". Now i have to go back from treeview and i dont know how. :/ My code: ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("#137$4300432741$43$False$False$False#")).Click();

Comment: edit: my code is only ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14");  - and i dont know how it works but this click "Syców" - i think this is just default then i click confirm ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_btnNetworkItemChoose"); and all its working. But if in future i want to click something else than for example "Syców" i dont know how do that.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the ID is unique
`ClickElementByXPath("//*[@id='#137$4300432740$43$False$False$False#']");`

Comment: People please help me. I am sitting at this in 4 hours.

Comment: It looks like you already found the solution. But, after reading your solution, I read your code as click the treeview first and then click the element with id  `"ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_btnNetworkItemChoose"`. I am not sure if the second element is `"Syców"` though, since the id is totally different. Would you provide the HTML code after you click the treeview?

Comment: Here is code http://wklej.org/id/2733948/  before this ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14");                                                                          - and after this                                                                                  SelectElementTextInSelectElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ddlWorkType", "SN");

Comment: I am pretty much confused with the html code that you sent me. It is incosistent with the original question and the one you commented here. The Id that you mentioned also is not available in the html code. So, I am sorry, but you really need to understand how to find the element and know what you wanted to do. I would suggest that you learn how html works and XPath in general. Starts with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath. Also make sure that you click a button `<button ....>` or `<input type="button">` instead of just text. Hidden button is because it has `<... type=hidden>`.

Comment: I know this element is not in html code because probably this element is in another application so i think i dont have access to this. I dont know what i  should do. Please if you can give me a hint or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
        ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_nitNetworkItem_ctl14");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        ClickElementById("ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderCenter_ContentPlaceHolderBody_btnNetworkItemChoose");

            This is half solved, because i dont know how click something else than "Syców".
```